# How to get total number of pages from a list of pdf files

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a list of 5 pdf files containing 20 pages each (suppose). I have to get a total number of pages of all the files. the answer will be 100 pages.

I have tried this :

```
val totalNumberOfFile = new File(uploadFolderPath)
val fileList = totalNumberOfFile.listFiles()
val totalPages = fileList.map(file => PDDocument.load(file).getNumberOfPages).sum
```

It is giving me the required answer but my question is:- Is it the best way to do this in scala

Comment: Yes, I think this is a good way of doing it. Of course you could make it to one line if you'd find that better. But it looks right to me

Comment: Will throw if `uploadFolderPath` is empty or contains any non-PDF files. None of the opened documents are getting closed.

Comment: ok, So will you suggest to me how to do this in a better way without getting any error or exception.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you want to do if the folder does not exist or is empty. In this example, I will simply consider that the number of pages is zero in that case.

Here is a sample using the modern Java Files API, and convert Java structures to Scala collections. It will run on Scala 2.13, but you might want to import `scala.collection.JavaConverters._` instead if running on previous versions of Scala.

```
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file._
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

// This object is provided by your library, I only defined it so my example can compile
object PDFDocument {
  def load(f: File) = new { def getNumberOfPages: Int = 1 }
}

val dir = Paths.get("/your/path/here")
val stream = if (Files.exists(dir)) Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.pdf").asScala.map(_.toFile) else Nil
val pages = stream.foldLeft(0)(_ + PDFDocument.load(_).getNumberOfPages)
```

The last line using `foldLeft` is just a fancy (potentially slightly more efficient) way of writing `stream.map(...).sum`, so you might want to prefer the later if you or your team isn't used to `fold` idioms.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [`scala.util.Using`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Using$.html) for automatic resource management and error handling, for example

```
scala.util.Using.Manager { use =>
  (new File(uploadFolderPath))
    .listFiles()
    .filter(_.getName.endsWith(".pdf"))
    .map(file => use(PDDocument.load(file)).getNumberOfPages)
    .sum
} match {
  case Success(sumOfPages) => println(sumOfPages)
  case Failure(error) => println("Failed to determine sum of pages", error)
}
```